# Ajax Post between angularjs and symfony2 (Notice: Undefined index)

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, symfony, post

I'm very new to symfony2 php framework but I know that its MVC for backend. I'm trying to create a form which get stored in the database and then an email is sent to the user with the same info that he/she typed in the form. To do that, I used doctrine, swiftmailer and entity in the symfony2 framework. 
When I use < form method='post' action='saveIndex' >< /form >, it works just fine but when I'm trying to implement angularjs's AJAX to post my data, I'm getting **Notice: Undefined index** error.

Html (in twig template):

```
<form class="productForm">
<div class="inputs" style="float: left">
<input type="text" name="productId" data-ng-model="signup.user.productId"/>
<input type="text" name="firstName" data-ng-model="signup.user.firstName"/>
<input type="text" name="lastName" data-ng-model="signup.user.lastName"/>
<input type="email" name="email" data-ng-model="signup.user.email"/>
<input type="text" name="price" data-ng-model="signup.user.price"/>
<input type="text" name="timeStamp" data-ng-model="signup.user.time"/>
<textarea name="comments" data-ng-model="signup.user.comments"></textarea>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng- click="submit(signup.user)">Submit Request</button>
</div>

</div>
</form>
```

app.js:

```
myApp.controller('mainController',[
    '$scope',
    '$location',
    '$http',
    '$window',
    '$rootScope',
    function($scope, $location, $http, $window, $rootScope){
            $scope.submit = function (user) {
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'saveIndex',
                        data: $scope.signup
                    })
                    .success(function(data, status){
                        $log.warn(data, status);  //remove for production
                        $location.path('success');

                    })
                    .error(function(data, status){
                        $log.warn(data, status); //remove for production
                    });
            }
    }
]);
```

symfony2 controller:

```
// Save Information
public function saveIndexAction(){
    $post = new Post();                  // Call to entity named Post
    $request = $this->get('request');
    $params = $request->request->all();
    $session = $this->get('session');
    $this->saveIndex(
        $params['productId'],           <- GETTING UNDEFINED INDEX ERROR
        $params['firstName'],
        $params['lastName'],
        $params['email'],
        $params['price'],
        $params['timeStamp'],
        $params['comments'],
        $session
    );

    $post->setProductId($params['productId']);
    $post->setFirstName($params['firstName']);
    $post->setLastName($params['lastName']);
    $post->setEmail($params['email']);
    $post->setPrice($params['price']);
    $post->setTimeStamp($params['timeStamp']);
    $post->setComments($params['comments']);

    // Store information in the database
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($post);
    $em->flush();

    // Send the email
    $this->mailAction
        (
            $post->getId(),
            $params['productId'],
            $params['firstName'],
            $params['lastName'],
            $params['email'],
            $params['price'],
            $params['timeStamp'],
            $params['comments']
        );

    // Return the response
    //return new Response('Info Submitted'.$post->getId());

    $return=json_encode($post);//json encode the array
    return new Response($return,200,array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));//make sure it has the correct content type
}
```

I don't know how to make AJAX POST with with symfony 2 controller and get the response back to Angularjs to perform client side routing. Please any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: your variable in angular is something like `signup.user.productId`, but you are trying to access this in Symfony using `productId`.  So that is where your issue is.  if you do a var dump of the `$params` variable in your controller, you will see how the array index is formed.

Comment: **improvement:** return a [`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse`](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.html) object instead of trying to create it yourself.

Comment: @Sehael....THANKS ALOT for the var_dump...I was struggling for a way to debug my code (same as debugger; in JS). When I did that, found out the $params is getting an empty array. So, I included the following code:

    if (is_array($p)) {
                foreach($p as $key=>$val) {
                    $params[$key]=$val;
                }
            }


AND IT WORKED. thank you SO MUCH

Answer (score 1):

So, upon var_dump($params), I found the output to be array (size = 0) undefined.

So, I included the following code:

```
protected function getRequestJson(){
    $params = null;
    $content = $this->get("request")->getContent();
    if (!empty($content))
    {
        $params = json_decode($content, true);
    }
    return $params;
}


public function saveIndexAction(){
    $post = new Post();

    $signup_params = $this->getRequestJson();

    //flatten signup parameters
    $params = array();
    foreach ($signup_params as $p) {
        if (is_array($p)) {
            foreach($p as $key=>$val) {
                $params[$key]=$val;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it worked.